# How to fix overloaded function with different signature

Tags: c++, overloading, clang++, derived-class

I am in the process of integrating a code base from another developer. I have stumbled over the following situation:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual void test(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "A::test(" << a << ')' << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    // using A::test;

    void test(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << "B::test(" << a << ", " << b << ')' << std::endl;
        A::test(a);
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.test(1, 2);
}
```

Compiling this code gives no warnings with `g++ -Wall`, but with `clang++ -Wall` I get:

```
x.cpp:15:11: warning: 'B::test' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
        void test(int a, int b)
             ^
x.cpp:5:19: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'A::test' declared here: different number of parameters (1 vs 2)
        virtual void test(int a)
                     ^
1 warning generated.
```

Output in both cases would be:

```
B::test(1, 2)
A::test(1)
```

How to resolve this situation? For me there is no clear path, since it is unclear what is the intention of the original programmer.

- It might be he wants to hide the version of `A::test` in `B` instances and only use the version with the additional argument (I think that's the case here).
- But I could use (the commented out) `using A::test` statement which gets rid of the warning, but calling `b.test(1)` would directly call into `A::test`, ignoring the overload. Most probably the original author does not want to expose `A::test` in `B` classes, too.
- Another idea would be to add the missing overload and make it raise an exception, like (in `B`):

  ```
  void test(int a)
  {
      throw std::logic_error("unsupported function overload");
  }
  ```

  But this feels bad since it's a runtime thing and I think there should be an error or a warning on compilation already.

Is there a canonical way to overload `A::test` and get rid of the warning in a way where I need not use `-Wno-overloaded-virtual`?

**Current solution**:

```
class B: public A
{
    private:
    using A::test;

    public:
    ...
};
```

This gets rid of the warning and will give an error if calling `b.test(1)`. It still makes it possible to call `A::test` on it of course ...

Comment: Since you do not override the function, there is no need to create it as `virtual`.

Comment: Why not ask the original author about his intentions?

Comment: @liliscent Well I don't know his intentions (100% certainity), but I have an idea (< 100% certainity) what he wants.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche He's currently not available :/ Else I would have of course :)

Comment: @hochl "currently"?  is it a permanent current, or a temporary current?

Comment: "but calling b.test(1) would directly call into A::test, ignoring the overload." If you want this call to result in a compilation error, just place the "using" in the private section.

Comment: My opinion is leaving the code as it is. When some place the base class method is called, compiler will give you error, then you know the original intention is overload not hide.

Comment: @n.m like I said in my answer; making it private means you can't call it as a B, but you can pass it around as an A ... which will re-expose the function.  The solution is to actually implement test in B so that it barfs if used if that's the real intention.

Comment: @UKMonkey It is already exposed in A. You cannot un-expose it by deriving from A. It is set in stone.

Comment: @n.m. no, it's hidden in B, thus unexposed... it's not set in stone, hence the question.

Comment: @UKMonkey An interface is a contract. By deriving from A publicly you promise to upheld A's contract. Breaking `A::test` breaks the promise, so don't do that

Comment: @UKMonkey I say "It is already exposed **in A**". You say "it us hidden "**in B**". There is no contradiction.

Comment: @n.m. it actually sounds like we're *trying* to agree with each other on some points :)

Comment: Wow that is a lot of response and an unexplained downvote (please clarify why you downvoted, whoever it is). @UKMonkey unavailable for a longer period -- too long to wait.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution or workaround might be to pull `A::test` into the scope of `B`, like

```
struct B : A
{
    using A::test;
    ...
};
```

Then you can use plain `test(a)` and `A::test` should be called.

Comment: I've upvoted this because, although OP mentions this approach already, it really is the right answer. In the unlikely event that the original programmer intended the function to be hidden, the narrowing of the parent-classes interface contract indicates a bad design decision somewhere, which is the thing that should be fixed so that the hiding is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

While you could make test(int) private in B, which will remove the warnings; you will end up with the situation that someone could trivially pass it as an "A" object and then call test(int) on it anyway.  I would not worry about the intentions of the original engineer since there's a work around to call test(int) and  make sure that what it does makes sense; even if that means throwing or failing to compile if used.